# Where and How I can modify the money_pattern of a MoneyType under Symfony 6

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony6

I would like to understand where and how I can cleanly modify the money_pattern of a MoneyType under Symfony 6.

I tried in :

- the twig.yaml
- the configureOptions of the MoneyType
- the parameters of the item (add function)

Impossible to apply the value :
`money_pattern => '{{ widget }} €'`

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`money_pattern` is fetched within the MoneyType based on the currency (so, 'EUR'). However, it is also affected by the locale that is set.

In (my own) default 'en', it is set to `€ {{ widget }}`, but after setting `\Locale::setDefault('de_DE');` the placement becomes `{{ widget }} €`.

That pattern comes from the PHP Extension ext-intl (or the symfony/polyfill-intl-icu - but the polyfill only has support for the 'en' locale).

If the currency is set as `false`, then the widget does not have a sign around it, and can be overridden in the twig/form template widgets, potentially overriding the `money_widget` custom form template.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.

Indeed, when I switch to local `fr_FR` in `translation.yaml > framework > default_language` the euro sign is switched to the right.